# Error: src/app/components/button/button.component.ts:11:27 - error TS1005: '(' expected

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to Angular and I'm following a tutorial to get started and I'm getting this error in line 11, even if '(' is present

Error: src/app/components/button/button.component.ts:11:27 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

this is the code of button.component.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  templateUrl: './button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button.component.css']
})
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() color: string;
  @Input() text: string;
  @Output() btnEvetn: new EventEmitter(); //line 11

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  onClick()
  {
    console.log("Added");
  }

}
```

also, I'm getting those other errors, all of them on line 11

Error: src/app/components/button/button.component.ts:11:27 - error TS2314: Generic type 'EventEmitter' requires 1 type argument(s).

Error: src/app/components/button/button.component.ts:11:39 - error TS1441: Cannot start a function call in a type annotation.

Error: src/app/components/button/button.component.ts:11:40 - error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.

Comment: Missing "=",   `@Output() btnEvetn = new EventEmitter(); `

Comment: Yeah it worked, it seems I missed that, thank you

Answer (score 0):

`@Output() btnEvetn: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter();`

Comment: No need to define data type.. it will be implicit 
`@Output() btnEvetn = new EventEmitter<string>();`

Comment: @xdeepakv of course there's "no need", being explicit vs. implicit is a matter of personal taste. In this case, I wanted to emphasize the difference between setting the type and setting the value.

Comment: You can just highlight.. missing "=", instead of giving code.